# [Python]: Array from CSV: set_data instead of x.append

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, append

my python program reads from a CSV with 3 columns, one of them is a datetime object. The code for reading it is as follows:

```
t=[]
y=[]
h=[]
readFile = open('document.csv', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()
for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
if plotPair in '. ':
    # skip. or space
    continue
if idx > 1:  # to skip the first line
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    time_string = xAndY[0]
    time_string1 = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    t.append(time_string1)
    y.append(float(xAndY[1]))
    h.append(float(xAndY[2]))
    print(len(y))
```

The CSV is being updated, new values are added to it. Because of this, the arrays are getting very large. How can I use set_data or something similar?

`t.set_data` does not seem to work for lists.

Comment: Can you please provide an example how your csv file looks like?

Comment: Firstly, Indent your code properly. Secondly, why not use `csv` module ? Lastly, what is set_data ?

Comment: pandas would save you a lot of lines. Why not use pandas module for your csv? It might even have solution to your problems

Comment: CSV rows look like this: 03/05/2017 09:40:19,21.2,35.0 and no one here really answered my question properly. How do I make the array only contain the amount of values the CSV has at that instant? Right now the array looks like this: [all_values][all_values+1][all_values+2]